# Maintainable API design for communication between Blazor WASM and ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly, api-design

I am seeking advice on how to design and implement the API between Blazor WebAssembly and ASP.NET Core server for a mid-size project (couple developers, few years). Here are approaches that I've tried and issues I've encountered.

**Approach #1: Put Entity classes to the Shared project and use them as the return type in Controller methods**

Pros:

- Simplicity - no boilerplate code
- Ensured type safety from database all the way to the client

Cons:

- In some cases the data should be processed on the server before they are returned - for example we don't need to return each product, but only the total count of products in a category. In some cases, the Client can work with simplified view of the data model - for example the Client only needs to know the price that's available to them, but database design needs to be more complex, so the Server could determine which price is available to which customer. In these cases we need to create a custom return type for the Controller method (Data Transfer Objects). This creates inconsistency, because some Controller methods return database entities, while some return DTOs. I found that these cases are so frequent that it's better to use DTOs for all communication.
- The Client usually doesn't use each field in the entity, but we transfer it anyway. This slows down the app for users with slow internet connection.

**Approach #2: Create one Data Transfer Object per entity, map with Entity.ToDataTransferObject()**

The Controller has many methods for querying data, to accomodate for needs of different Components on the client. Most often, the database result takes a form of an `Entity` or of `List<Entity>`. For each database entity, we have a method `entity.ToDataTransferObject()` which transforms the database result to a DTO from Shared project.

For cases when the response type is very different from database entities, we create distinct data transfer object and do the transformation either in Controller method or in a distinct class.

Pros:

- Data model on the Client is just as complex as it needs to be

Cons:

- Some controller methods load (and need return) all data about an entity, and about its related entities, going into depth of 5. Some methods only need to load two simple fields. Because we use the same `entity.ToDataTransferObject()` method for all of them, they need to share the same return type. Any field which is not *always* returned is declared as nullable. This has BAD consequences. The compiler no longer ensures the compatibility of the Blazor Component with the return type of the Controller method. The compiler doesn't ensure compatibility of the database query with the `entity.ToDataTransferObject()` method. The compatibility is only discovered by testing, and that is only if the right data are present in the database. As app development continues and the data model evolves, this is a great source of bugs.
- There are multiple controller methods querying the same data. The queries contain some business logic (for example - which products should be displayed to this customer?). When there are multiple controller methods querying the same data, this business logic is duplicated into multiple controller methods. Even worse, sometimes the logic is duplicated into other controllers, when we need to decide which entity to include.

**Now I am looking for Approach #3**

The cons of Approch #2 lead me to the following design changes:

- Stop making properties of Data Transfer Object nullable, to signify that they have not have been loaded from the database. If a property has't been loaded, we need to create a new class for the transfer object, where the property will not be present.
- Stop using `entity.ToDataTransferObject()` - one master-method to convert an entity to Data Transfer Object. Instead, create a method for every type of DataTransferObject.
- Find a way to extract parts of EF Core queries to re-usable methods to prevent duplicating business logic.

However, this would require us to add a mountain of additional code ️. We would need to create a new class for each subset of properties of an entity, which is used in a component. This might be worth it, considering it's likely to eliminate majority of bugs that we face today, but it's a heavy price to pay.

**Have I missed anything? Is there any better design that I haven't considered?**

Comment: I don't think this question is focused enough for Stack Overflow. It will probably attract opinionated answers. This seems better suited for [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: By the way, you could consider more types of DTO per entity. Or maybe there is an underlying design issue: the entities are too big/have too many responsibilities. You might want to split them up. And sending the original entity is not a good idea imho as it couples the data types to the API, so if you ever change the data type, you break the API. You want those decoupled for user-facing APIs.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, use DTO’s to match the client side UI view model. So UI-formatted values, along with record ID values to allow posting updates from edit forms. This ensures no accidental unauthorized access to any values that the current session has no permissions for, and it prevents overfetching data in general.